# If you roll four dice, what are the odds of getting three ones?

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

Using the run-of-the-mill d6, naturally.

Comment: You seem to be new to the site and may be wondering why your question was put 'on hold', meaning that no additional answers can be posted. On this site, we expect questions to show some attempts at solution, where you got stuck answering, and some information on where the question comes from. That way we can give the most helpful answers. (This is not a 'homework answering' site.) In this case, is the brief answer from @DougM enough, or did you need a long-winded answer such as mine?

Answer (score 2):

(1/6)(1/6)(1/6)(5/6)(4)=20/1296

Comment: Simple and to the point. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

**Binomial distribution:**

$n = 4,$ $P(\text{get a 1}) = P(Success) = 1/6.$
If $X =$ the number of 1's in 4 rolls then
$$P(X = 3) = {4 \choose 3}(1/6)^3(5/6) = 0.0154.$$

```
 choose(4,3)*(1/6)^3*(5/6)
 ## 0.0154321
 dbinom(3, 4, 1/6)
 ## 0.0154321
```

If it's $P(X \ge 3)$ you want, then the answer is
$P(X = 3) + P(X = 4) = 0.0162.$

```
 sum(dbinom(3:4, 4, 1/6))
 ## 0.01620370
```

[image]